# How does SOLOSHOT work?

Tags: camera, gps, reverse-engineering

Does anyone know how [SOLOSHOT](http://soloshot.com/) works?

I'm interested in exploring cheap ways of tracking an object relative to another object. So my brother sent me a link to this product and I'm having trouble figuring out how it works.

Basically, the user has an arm band and the camera tracks this user.

I have found a few things:

1. it doesn't work too well when the user covers the armband
2. it takes about 8 minutes to boot up
3. it does not need LOS
4. it works best if viewing from 200 ft away
5. it works even when traveling 140 mph

My initial guess is GPS and a radio signal to talk to each other which would make sense with the criteria 1-4 listed above (I remember my GPS units needing to find satellites for a couple minutes when booting up), but can GPS really track your position that fast?

More information about what this sensor is: http://soloshot.com/index.php?module=product&action=product_details&pid=87

Comment: The page you linked to is just a flashy ad.  It doesn't even say what this thing actually is, let alone how it works.

Comment: My point is that I don't know how it works... If I had a site that explained how it works I wouldn't have come here. If you clicked "Learn More" it would take you to the page that talks more about what it is. http://soloshot.com/index.php?module=product&action=product_details&pid=87

Comment: Yes, but your link doesn't even explain *what* it is.

Comment: Very thought-provoking question, that would excite anyone with an actual engineering, problem solving mind-set. Excellent!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *probably* differential GPS, although it might just be two independant regular GPS recievers (hence the minimum suggested distance). All of the product photos show it outdoors, another requirement for GPS.

GPS can work at extremely high speeds once it's acquired a good lock; consumer units are not "allowed" to operate at more than 512m/s (about 1800kph) to prevent their use in amateur guided missile systems.

The communication between devices might have an effective speed limit, disguised by using linear prediction, so if you're cornering in a Formula 1 car it might not be entirely reliable.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't realize GPS sensors could accurately work at speeds that high.

Comment: I thought differential GPS required fancy antenns because you need to look at the phase of the signal, not just the pseudocode... but then there's the Piksi and stuff so I dunno, maybe you're right.